# Alert Script : Cannot set property 'action' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, alert, sweetalert

I have a code that has a datatable and an alert pop out. Datatable works fine with or without the alert pop but alert pop does not work well with datatable. Only works without it(datatable). Is this a possible code conflict? The error suggests that a "TypeError: Cannot set property 'action' of undefined" in users.js:27 (line 27) when I try to delete the data. Same thing goes to confirm (line 49).

Here is my HTML(form) code

```
<table class="table table-striped datatable" id="datatables">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>


                   <?php
                      if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // output data of each row?>
                       <tbody>
                           <?php  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                              if($row['status']=='t'){
                      ?>
                              <form name="frmUser" action="" method="post"> 
                              <?php {                         //this form will display the set of pending applications

                                      echo'<tr>';
                                      echo '<td>' . '<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="'.$row['application_number'].'" class="checkbox-warning"/>' . '</td>';
                                      echo '<td>' . $row['application_number'] . '</td>';
                                      echo '<td>' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>';
                                      echo '<td>' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
                                  echo'</tr>';
                                  }
                              ?>

                      <?php    } //if statement
                               } //while statement
                      ?>
                        </tbody>  
                      </table>
                          <input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"  id="onDelete" />
                          <input type="button" name="update" value="Confirm"  id="onUpdate" />
                          </form>

                      <?php
                      }else {
                          echo "0 results";
                      }
            ?>
```

Then here's my
JS Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$( "#onDelete" ).click(function() {
    swal({   title: "Are you sure?",   
        text: "You will not be able to recover this file!",   
        type: "warning",   
        showCancelButton: true,   
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel!",   
        closeOnConfirm: false,   
        closeOnCancel: false 
    }, function(isConfirm){   
        if (isConfirm) {
            document.frmUser.action = "temporary_applications_delete.php"; 
            document.frmUser.submit();       
            swal("Deleted!", "Application file has been deleted.", "success");

        } else {     
            swal("Cancelled", "Your file is safe :)", "error");   
        } });

});

$( "#onUpdate" ).click(function() {
    swal({   title: "Are you sure?",   
        text: "You will UPDATE this applicant file!",   
        type: "warning",   
        showCancelButton: true,   
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, UPDATE it!",   
        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel!",   
        closeOnConfirm: false,   
        closeOnCancel: false 
    }, function(isConfirm){   
        if (isConfirm) {
            document.frmUser.action = "temporary_applications_process.php"; 
            document.frmUser.submit();       
            swal("Updated!", "Application file has been updated!.", "success");

        } else {     
            swal("Cancelled", "Your file is safe :)", "error");   
        } });

});
```

});

What went wrong with the codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an html problem because you open form tag inside table body and closed it after table you must close form inside table body
as html tags must be closed properly.

Comment: if you have a problem don't hesitate to as again

Comment: Didn't see that hah! Great! That solved the problem. Thanks for pointing that out.